# Can I by any means get the elapsed time of the storyboard in Silverlight?

Tags: silverlight, storyboard

Can I by any means get the elapsed time of the storyboard in Silverlight?

```
Storyboard _timer = new Storyboard();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try Storyboard.GetCurrentTime

Colin E.